# Mongodb high levels of page faults, how can I fix this?

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, memory

I am running a local mongodb for my API services. I noticed when I ran db.serverStatus() it said that I have close to 2 million page faults for session.

How much does this effect performance and how do I fix this? What is a normal amount?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running on Windows? Page faults can be inaccurate and absurdly high due to counting both soft and hard page faults. This is a [known bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SERVER-5799) with with mongodb on Windows.

Because of this, the number you see does not correlate well to the actual performance of your DB, and is a poor indicator of issues typically associated with page faults like frequently accessed data not fitting in RAM.

To my knowledge, there's no way to fix this on Windows without building a customized version of MongoDB from source. The JIRA issue has existed for many years and has been marked `Will not fix`.

On a healthy system, page faults should be kept as low as possible. Quick occasional spikes up to a couple thousand are okay, but sustained high numbers of page faults indicate performance issues.

Comment: Yes, I am running on windows.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my answer to address the question better. Please upvote or mark accepted if you found this helpful!